# Does Family Safety record site visits on a virtualbox?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine

So my son has been seeing some very disturbing stuff lately. So I decided to setup family safety. But he uses his ***Ubuntu VM*** most of the time and I would like to know if the family safety can record the sites he visits or will it just let me know if he is using the virtualbox.

Note: I don't wanna setup family safety before being absolutely sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Family Safety is a feature of Windows Live, which is limited to Windows only.

He will not be affected in his Ubuntu VM if you setup Family Safety.

In order to affect everyone and everything, set filters on your router.

Some routers have specific filters that can be enabled/disabled, such as adult content, casino, drugs, violents, etc. These filters are not 100% proof, but should block almost everything. (only sites that do not use web standards may pass) For sex sites, those will be very few. Its more likely to be the case with drugs, casino or violent related sites to not follow the standards.

Comment: But its still a bit hazy. Will i get to know if he is visiting sex sites or will it say that that he was using his VM. What I understood from your answer is that it wont block the sites but will I get notified like I'm supposed to?

Comment: You will not even be able to detect it. A router has logs, and they can show it in the logs as the sites visited, but thats it. You may also be able to get the ip address that was associated with the visit, and conclude who it was from there. It depends on the router if it can do this and how well it can.